# AngularJS 1, Passing value of button

Tags: angularjs

Probably a very simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer that works. I'm trying to pass the `{{data}}` inside a button on click through a function, `revealNumbers`.

```
<button class="select" ng-click="revealNumbers(firstNumber)">{{firstNumber}}</button>
<button class="select" ng-click="revealNumbers(secondNumber)">{{secondNumber}}</button>
```

Controller:

```
            $scope.revealNumbers = function(num) {

                $scope.result = num
                console.log($scope.result)

        var randomInteger = (getRandomInt(1, 2))
if (randomInteger==2) {
            $scope.firstNumber = 5
            $scope.secondNumber = 10
        } else if ( randomInteger ==1) {
            $scope.firstNumber = 3
            $scope.secondNumber = 8
        }
        }
```

I get `undefined` in the console. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` should be properties on the `$scope`. If they are undefined on the scope so will the passed in parameter value be undefined.

Comment: Please show how you set a value of `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`.

Comment: Sorry, edited now.

Comment: Also wrong, you should set the values of `secondNumber` and `firstNumber` **outside** of your method. Like in the controller's or directive's constructor for example.

Comment: Oh okay, maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Not sure how to explain this any more: You call `revealNumbers` and pass in `firstNumber` **but** you do not even set `firstNumber` until inside `revealNumbers`, how you can expect the parameter to have a value??

Comment: Thanks @Igor that was it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Declaration of values should be outside callback function, so get those two lines:

```
$scope.secondNumber = 5
$scope.firstNumber = 10
```

before Your  `$scope.revealNumbers` declaration.

Your current implementation initialize those variables after button click ( in click event callback ), so the first click will give error because variables are undefined, next ones will work.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to your handler an angularJS $event obejct and reference the element innerText from this $event object.

So your code should look as follows:

```js
angular.module('newModule', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.firstName = "Jenkins";
  $scope.lastName = "Lincoln";
  
  $scope.revealNumbers = function(event){
    console.log(event.target.innerText);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="newModule" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
  <button class="select" ng-click="revealNumbers($event)">{{firstName}}</button>
  <button class="select" ng-click="revealNumbers($event)">{{lastName}}</button>
</div>
```